# How to pass some parameter from before method to after in aspectj

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

Below is the code for my aspectJ class

```
public aspect TestAspect {
String str;
long time;
pointcut callLoggingAspect():call(* com.dilip.bdp..*.*(..));
before() : callLoggingAspect() {
    str = thisJoinPoint.getSignature().toShortString();
    time = System.nanoTime();
}
after() : callLoggingAspect() {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint.getSignature().toShortString()+":Before="+str);
    System.out.println("Time taken by method "+thisJoinPoint.getSignature().toShortString()+" to execute ="+(System.nanoTime()-time));
}
```

}

What I need is to capture some thing in before() and use that value in after() for same method.
My this current code where I am setting some value is class level variable, is not working in multithreaded environment .
Please suggest me how can I achive it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple: Use an `around()` advice instead. No need for any advanced tricks here.